# Connecting to a database using only VueJs

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, vue.js, frontend

I am working on an application that will be internally used.
It is a accounting and inventory management webApp.
The question is can i connect to the database from the front end and skip the backend ?

Comment: Not sure if it is possible, but even if it is, not a good thing to do.  You don't want to expose your database in a browser.  Separation of responsibilities.  Look at adding a REST api layer and call that from the front-end

Comment: listen to @OldProgrammer ... not a good idea at all !!